# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker timing out after inactivity during long computation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to run a very long numerical simulation - up to 20 hours. The code works beautifully when I tell it to do a short, 20 second simulation. However, when running a longer one, I get the error "The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own)".

After browsing the web, it seems to me that the issue is that Elastic Beanstalk allows worker processes to run for 30 minutes at most, and then they time out because the instance has not responded (i.e. finished the simulation). The solution some have proposed is to send a message every 30 seconds or so that "pings" Elastic Beanstalk, letting it know that the simulation is going well so it doesn't time out, which would let me run a long worker process. So I have a few questions:

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. If so, what code or configuration would I add to the project to make it stop terminating early?
3. If not, how can I smoothly run a 12+ hour simulation on AWS or more generally, the cloud?

**Add on information**
Thank you for the feedback, Rohit. To give some more information, I'm using Python with Flask.

• I am indeed using an Elastic Beanstalk worker tier with SQS queues

• In my code, I'm running a simulation of variable length - from as short as 20 seconds to as long as 20 hours. 99% of the work that Elastic Beanstalk does is running the simulation. The other 1% involves saving results, sending emails, etc.

• The simulation itself involves using generating many random numbers and working with objects that I defined. I use numpy heavily here.

Let me know if I can provide any more information. I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Are you using Elastic Beanstalk worker tier with SQS queues? What part of your code takes 20 seconds? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to a friend who's more in the know about this stuff than me, I solved the problem. It's a little sketchy, but got the job done. For future reference, here is an outline of what I did:

1) Wrote a main script that used Amazon's boto library to connect to my SQS queue. Wrote an infinite while loop to poll the queue every 60 seconds. When there's a message on the queue, run a simulation and then continue through with the loop

2) Borrowed a beautiful /etc/init.d/ template to run my script as a daemon (http://blog.scphillips.com/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/)

3) Made my main script and the script in (2) executable

4) Set up a cron job to make sure the script would start back up if it failed.

Once again, thank you Rohit for taking the time to help me out. I'm glad I still got to use Amazon even though Elastic Beanstalk wasn't the right tool for the job

Comment: Does this mean the worker instance is constantly polling and therefore being charged for usage?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you are running into launches timing out because some commands during launch that run on your instance take more than 30 minutes.
As explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html), you can adjust the `Timeout` option in the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:command` namespace. This can have values between 1 and 1800. This means if your commands finish within 30 minutes you won't see this error. The commands might eventually finish as the error message says but since Elastic Beanstalk has not received a response within the specified period it does not know what is going on your instance.

It would be helpful if you could add more details about your usecase. What commands you are running during startup? Apparently you are using ebextensions to launch commands which take a long time. Is it possible to run those commands in the background or do you need these commands to run during server startup?

If you are running a Tomcat web app you could also use something like servlet init method to run app bootstrapping code. This code can take however long it needs without giving you this error message.

Comment: Rohit, I appreciate your help. What exactly do you mean by commands I'm running during startup? The message passes from Amazon SQS to a function I have called "run_model()", and this function does a variety of things. Its main job is to call another function - which is where all of the heavy-lifting is - and save the results from that function and then return a response. Can I call this other function asynchronously?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying you are using worker tier. The above explanation was for commands in ebxtensions timing out.

From your clarification it seems that it can take between 20 seconds to 20 hours to process SQS messages in your worker environment. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Rohit, I'm not sure what you mean by my commands in ebextensions. I don't have a .ebextensions folder (maybe that's my problem?). It can take anywhere from 20 seconds to 20 hours (but I control how long it takes) to execute the simulation that the worker process is supposed to handle. Is it possible that other commands are running that I don't know about?

Comment: .ebextensions is optional. You use it when you need it. I was suspecting you had ebextensions which had commands taking a long time. But since you don't have one that point is moot. To dig deeper into this error: "The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own)", can you snapshot your logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html to see detailed log messages?

Comment: Here's the log file. I've googled a ton of the messages there but I've had no success :( https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-277193063490.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-dvbgjamm3j/i-2be17779/TailLogs-1404511834959.out?Expires=1404598235&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOUOORMVUTXOJUHQ&Signature=sHz0GEbhrSYZ32gEHvsKZz1%2BCoM%3D

Comment: I think the issue is that my code doesn't finish, and therefore doesn't send a response, within the InactivityTimeout period. Is that right?

Comment: Since you say that a 20 second simulation runs fine but a 20 hour simulation fails, like you suggest it could be a problem with the inactivity timeout. Can you try tweaking the inactivity timeout a bit to see if a 20 minute simulation runs fine?

Comment: Looking at your logs you have several 'http-err' messages in /var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log with HTTP 500 error. "When the web application in the worker environment tier returns a 200 OK response to acknowledge that it has received and successfully processed the request, the daemon sends a DeleteMessage call to the SQS queue so that the message will be deleted from the queue." See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html Can you confirm that your application is setting response code to 200 to signify successfully processed messages?

Comment: Yes, I just double checked the code. When my simulation runs correctly, it returns a 200 OK response code. I tried to max out the InactivityTimeout parameter to 1800, the largest allowed value, but still only the 20 second simulation works

Comment: Do you know if it's even possible to run 20 hour simulations on an Elastic Beanstalk worker tier. If so, then what exactly does the InactivityTimeout parameter do, since the most it can be is 30 minutes? I know I'm not going to be able to send a 200 response back until the simulation is done. Is that the issue I'm having here?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to 'process a message' from an SQS queue for more than 12 hours (see the description of [ChangeVisibilityTimeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html)).
With that being the case, this approach doesn't fit your application well. I have ran into the same problem.

**The correct way to do this:** I don't know. However, I would suggest an alternate approach where you grab a message off of your queue, spin off a thread or process to run your long running simulation, and then delete the message (signaling successful processing). In this approach, be careful of spinning off too many threads on one machine and also be wary of machines shutting down before the simulation has ended, because the queue message has already been deleted.
Final note: your question is excellently worded and sufficiently detailed :)

Comment: Thanks Jason, I appreciate your input. I solved the issue last week by eating the frog and learning how to use a bare EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to run jobs shorter than 10 hours, it needs to be mentioned that the current inactivity timeout limit is 36000 seconds, so exactly 10 hours and not anymore 30 minutes, like mentioned in posts all over the web (which led me to think a workaround like described above is needed).

Check out the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

A very nice write-up can be found here: https://dev.to/rizasaputra/understanding-aws-elastic-beanstalk-worker-timeout-42hi