# How can I increase timeouts of AWS worker tier instances?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run background processes on an Elastic Beanstalk single worker instance within a Docker container and have not been able execute a request/job for longer than 60 seconds without getting a 504 timeout.

Looking at the log files provided by AWS the issue begins with the following error;

```
[error] 2567#0: *37 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /queue/work HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.3:80/queue/", host: "localhost"
```

Does anyone know if it possible to increase the limit from 60 seconds to a longer period as I would like to generate some reports which will take 3 to 4 minutes to process.

I have increased the NGINX timeout settings within .ebextensions/nginx-timeout.config without any results.

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf":     mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      proxy_connect_timeout       600;
      proxy_send_timeout          600;
      proxy_read_timeout          600;
      send_timeout                600;
commands:
  "00nginx-create-proxy-timeout":
    command: "if [[ ! -h /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf ]] ; then ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy-timeout.conf ; fi"
```

I have also increased the PHP max_execution_time within a custom php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 600
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35192287, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24505091

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the Load Balancer's Idle timeout setting. The default is 60 seconds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html?icmpid=docs_elb_console

Comment: Also see connection-idle-timeout for [*application* load balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout)